# Convert date format using VF code...?

Tags: visualforce

How to covert date from  2015-10-08 10:56:13  to 10/8/2015 10:56 AM  format using Visual force page??

Comment: I am getting the result through query  as 2015-10-08 10:56:13 but  I want to display the date in format like  10/8/2015 10:56 AM   .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an Example to output the date time as you requested. My DateTime format is a bit different in my local which is why it is slightly different that yours:

The class simply constructs the DateTime and has a method to return it

**CLASS**

```
public class myTest{


    DateTime tmp = DateTime.parse('10/08/2015 10:56 AM');

    public DateTime getTmpDate(){
        return tmp;
    }    



}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="myTest">

    <apex:outPutText value="{0,date,short} {1,time,short}">
        <apex:param value="{!DATEVALUE(tmpDate)}"/>
        <apex:param value="{!DATETIMEVALUE(tmpDate)}"/>
    </apex:outPutText>


</apex:page>
```

The VF Page uses the Java Message Format to display the  output as appropriate. The outPutText has two merge syntaxes, the 0 and 1 are the paramaters provided within the tag block. The params pass in the Date value first and the date time value second.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

In case link goes stale do a google search for

> Java Message Format

*An alternate way to do it is:*

```
<apex:outputText value="string: {0,date,yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z}"> <apex:param value="{!tmpDate}" /> </apex:outputText>
```

and it gives you extremely precise control